# namespace inclusion in header and template classes

Tags: c++, coding-style

Well, this is not a real programming issue, but more about good/bad practice

I'm working of my final project of CSP course which is a library with several solvers. Most classes are heavily templated. AFAIK there is no elegant way to separate source and header to get a clean binary and development staff. Actually there is no real binary here. Code generation stage will be done by compiler when within final code.

On the other hand, I'm using boost asio library to do networking staff in a portable manner. From basic programming course, I know it's known as a bad practice to use `using namespace` in headers. Because doing so will limit final user to use a more limited naming options within his/her private code, and is more conflict prone.

Finally, to make code clear I would like to `unisg namespcae` or `using` in my code. My question is what is best way to do so? Am I doing this wrong? Currently I'm using `using`s inside functions in header (not at global scope) like this:

```
// File : abt-solver.h
template<typename valueType>
inline void AIT::ABT_Solver<valueType>::connect() {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;    // <===== Here
    using namespace std;           // <===== And here
    tcp::resolver::query query(this->address, this->portNumber);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
    // blah blah blah ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since using the `using` inside a limited scope does not affect the parent namespace or or namespace of the including file i do not see any problems.

regarding separation of source from declarations:
boost uses the following scheme:
the declarations reside in a *.hpp file and the implementations are in another file (i could not recall the extension atm).

at the end of the hpp htey include the file with the definitions.
Of course you have to remember that every thing that is declared in the implmentation file is also visible to the header.  so still no using is allowed

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fine to use `using` at function scope, it doesn't affect anything outside that function.